# Why is the 'Date' not append into the <div>?

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

[image]

I am using bootstrap DateTimePicker, as you can see, the 'Start Date' is able to append the text into the `<div>` in `#shadow-root` but the 'Expiry Date' is unable to do so. The 'Start Date' is able to append automatically after the page load, how can I append the Expiry Date into the `<div>` like 'Start Date' ? Codes below are the code for the datetimepicker.

```
                     <div class="form-group row m-b-15">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Start Date :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1vs" name="start_date">
                                <input type="text" name="start_date" class="form-control"
                                       value="{{date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($voucher->start_date))}}"
                                       placeholder="Select a Start Date"/>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Expiry Date :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1ve" name="expiry_date">
                                <input type="text" name="expiry_date" class="form-control"
                                       value="{{date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($voucher->expiry_date))}}"
                                       placeholder="Select an Expiry Date"/>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm lol, I just realized the format that I've given is not the same as required in bootstrap.js